# Minimize CentOS image

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

I want to reduce the size of my CentOS installation. So I want to uninstall some extra packages if possible. Example: centos-logos 70.0.6

So I want to see if there is a package that is dependent on this package so that I don't screw up my OS.

Comment: Please check whether your question is answered here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077538/check-rpm-dependencies

Comment: It would be some difficult because lot of dependencies. Minimal centos install about 2.5 gb

Comment: I think the OP tries to reduce them, which is possible, but should happen without the break of the dependencies. The essence of the question is, how to do that.